# How to fix Excel-2016 not running Excel-2010 VBA code for printing correctly?

Tags: vba, excel

This loop runs typically 4 to 8 times. It updates 30+ textboxes and prints. Has been working great. But we updated from office 2010 to 2016 (and to Office 365), so now it runs but all the textboxes on the printed pages have the same value from iteration 1. Happens on all printers including PDFcreator. But afterwards the sheet is in the state I expect for the last iteration. It's like the code outruns the printer. But adding a delay of even 10 sec does not help. Oddly, as I try different things I see on the first iter that the textboxes update (from the previous runs last iter). Seems like it should update every iter.

```
Sub printParamSheets()
On Error GoTo errHandler
Dim Bin1_Matl, Bin1_Parts 'Declaring types won't help or speed up
Dim iCond, conditions

Application.EnableEvents = True 'Is not helping with issue

For iCond = 1 To conditions

    With Sheet2
        'Assign from sheet2 to variables
        Bin1_Matl = .Range("A64").Offset(0, iCond * 2).Value2
        Bin1_Parts = .Range("B64").Offset(0, iCond * 2).Value2
        'about 30 more of these
    End With

    With Sheet8 'Assign Sheet8 named ranges from variables above. 
            'Could skip intermed vars but nice for debugging.
            'ALL LINKED TO ACTIVEX TEXT BOXES on Sheet8, atop an image.
        .Range("Bin1Matl").Value2 = Bin1_Matl
        .Range("Bin1Parts").Value2 = Bin1_Parts
        'about 30 more of them
        .Calculate  'Is not helping with issue

        Dim ctrl As OLEObject  'Is not helping with issue
        For Each ctrl In .OLEObjects
            If TypeName(ctrl.Object) = "TextBox" Then
                'ctrl.Update    'error, but was not in 2010 anyway
            End If              
        Next ctrl

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))  'Is not helping 
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Never toggled off , no help
        DoEvents    'Is not helping with issue

        .PrintOut from:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
    End With
Next iCond

Exit Sub
errHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True 'Don't need but cannot hurt
Resume Next
End Sub
```

I will try skipping the extra intermediate assignments, going straight from sheet2 to the textboxes. But I'd like to know the cause because I have other code 'in the wild' that doesn't necessarily use any activex objects that may be affected. Hoping the symptom is not unique to our site and so others may benefit from an answer.

Comment: Remove the error handler at the beginning **On Error GoTo errHandler** and let us know what is the error code and message when you run it.

Comment: When ctrl.update is not commented out, Update Method of OLEObject Failed. But I just dropped that bit in thinking it would help - it was not in the original code that ran well. I should figure out how to do it right, maybe it would help. Note there is no sheet protection on to get in the way.

Comment: Doing ctrl.activate instead actually works to print correctly. Horribly inefficient in a way but no worse than putting a 3 second delay in. I'll do this but I'm not happy about it.

Comment: Can you Activate Sheet8 before the With Sheet8 section and try the ctrl.Update ? there is a possibility that the control will not update if the sheet is not active. Just a guess.

Comment: @RicardoA, Thanks, I tried. Still errs. Compiles, but at run time errs. I can live with my workaround. Curious what may be going on under the hood to cause behavior to change. My guess is it is unintended consequence of some improvement.